# Não foi possível carregar o arquivo solicitado: produtos / lista_tabela.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Estou tentando exibir em uma `view` dados vindo do banco de dados, quando tentei executar apareceu a seguinte mensagem:

> ```
> Um erro encontrado    
> Não foi possível carregar o arquivo solicitado: produtos / lista_tabela.php
> ```

produtos = nome da minha pasta
lista_tabela = nome da minha view

e no controller :

```
$this->load->view("produtos/lista_tabela", $dados);
```

O que poderia está causando esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, um dos possíveis motivos seria que você tenha digitado o arquivo errado, cheque novamente se todos os nomes estão certos.

Outro motivo, é que até onde eu sei, o codeigniter só procura arquivos views com o súfixo `.php`, então se a sua `lista_tabela`, esteja como `.html`, troque para `.php` e veja se vai funcionar.

Comment: Obrigada! Consegui